# Change math font style from tufte-book class to svjour3 class without changing too much in the preamble

Tags: math-fonts

I know that the two math fonts used are like default fonts, I think svjour3 uses Latin Modern Roman and tufte-book XITS, I just didn't find an easy way to set the math font. I want to avoid using extra packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just for clarification: would you like to use the Computer Modern fonts like in `svjour3` in `tufte-book` or the Palatino fonts (not XITS) of `tufte-book` in `svjour3`?

Comment: The reason is, I wrote a paper in svjour3 which I am now using in a report of the class tufte-book. So I want to use the same math fonts from svjours in my report. (so the first option)

Comment: I'm not seeing why. Math is independent on the font it's typeset with.

Comment: I am referring to equations and figures in the paper and I would like to have the same 'looks' when I use them or rewriting them. I thought that changing some math font styles should be easy like 'a going back to default setting' or something. But if this is not the case I will be happy with any suggestion.